# Forcing InnoDB to build the secondary index

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb, innodb, mariadb-10.5

When `INSERT`ing, `InnoDB` defers the building of secondary indexes. For example,

```
CREATE TABLE item_creators
(
item_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
creator_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
INDEX(creator_id),
PRIMARY KEY(item_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

After the first query,

```
INSERT INTO item_creators (item_id,creator_id)
    SELECT item_id,creator_id FROM t1;

SELECT a.item_id, b.creator FROM
    item_creators a JOIN creators ON a.creator_id=b.creator_id;
```

`InnoDB` starts to rebuild the secondary index, `INDEX(creator_id)` in background. Without this index, the second query is quite slow.

- First, how can we force `InnoDB` to rebuild the secondary index after
  the first query?
- Second, how can we check if the required index has been completed before running the second query?

Note that it's about very large tables (hundreds of millions of rows) where the index building takes time.

Comment: Is this related to the default [innodb_ibuf_max_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_ibuf_max_size)?

Comment: @danblack sorry for the previous comment. I meant `innodb_ibuf_accel_rate`. Anyhow, disabling `change buffer` will reduce the speed of large `INSERT`s. It is good to have the change buffer, but I want to flush it right after the query.

Comment: @danblack I believe `innodb_ibuf_max_size` is now `innodb_change_buffer_max_size`, as InnoDB changed the terminology, though `Ibuf` is still used in STATUS.

Comment: Since the change buffer is probably dirty pages in the buffer pool. Does temporary dropping the global `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct` force the flushing?

Comment: @danblack I thought so, but in my experience, the secondary index is not part of the change buffer/dirty pages. InnoDB rebuild it later. After a large `INSERT`, empty the buffer pool. Then, InnoDB starts to rebuild the secondary index, as can be judged from `I/O` activities and refilling buffer pool (in the absence of any running query).

Comment: Those sound like 5.5 variables: Old variable innodb_ibuf_accel_rate was renamed to innodb_ibuf_merge_rate. Bug fixed: [#695906](https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/695906)

Comment: @danblack - The change buffer is for changes to non-unique indexes; think of it as a "delayed write".  It does not prevent the use of the indexes.  I do not think the secondary index is ever "rebuilt" without an explicit action by the user.

Comment: @Googlebot - What version?

Comment: Default for dirty pages is most of the buffer_pool; default for the change buffer is 25%.  They are separate.

Comment: In certain types of loads (I don't know which), secondary indexes are _built_ (not _rebuilt_) after loading the data.

Comment: @RickJames, the secondary index is not built, as the table already has rows and the index exists. The correct verb is *to update* rather than *to rebuild*, but not *to build

Comment: @RickJames, it's MariaDB 10.5 per tag. I believe `innodb_ibuf_merge_rate` is a Perconna variable. I am looking for the equivalent in MariaDB.

Comment: @Googlebot - I believe my Answer [now] has the equivalents.  They were probably adopted from MySQL at 10.0 time.  (I don't know whether MySQL adopted the ibuf code or whether they re-invented it.)

Comment: @RickJames no, as discussed above, reducing `innodb_change_buffer_max_size` is not the solution. We need to use the change buffer but flush the pages aggressively. My understanding is that InnoDB does not update the secondary indexes until finishing the main changes. InnoDB updates the secondary index in the background with low priority. I want to do it as fast as possible and check when it is fully updated. Even with `innodb_change_buffering=0`, when the query has been finished, the secondary index has not been fully updated (it is undergoing in the background).

Comment: @Googlebot In your question about when is the background finished, you might wish to consider  FLUSH TABLE (tablename); before requesting query 2.  That should have the effect of WAIT until the index activity is truly DONE and on your data storage media.

Comment: @Googlebot - "InnoDB does not update the secondary indexes until..." -- That refers to the _disk_ blocks.  The Change buffer is effectively a temporary RAM-based extension of the BTree on disk.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have some misunderstandings. When you insert a row, InnoDB doesn't rebuild the whole index. It just adds an entry to the existing index. It would be incredibly bad for performance if it had to rebuild the index on a large table after every INSERT.

Another misunderstanding is about the deferred index update. The index is still usable during this time. InnoDB knows how to check entries that are in the change buffer as well as the index. If a query reads a value from the change buffer, this causes it to be merged into the index immediately. If a query reads other values that are already merged into the index, the index helps that query.

You might be trying to solve a problem that does not exist.

As for the question you asked, how to tell if the index is fully merged, it's tricky to do this. You can query to see how much of the buffer pool is allocated to the change buffer (this is documented on this manual page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-change-buffer.html)

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE
       WHERE PAGE_TYPE LIKE 'IBUF%') AS change_buffer_pages,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE) AS total_pages,
       (SELECT ((change_buffer_pages/total_pages)*100))
       AS change_buffer_page_percentage;

+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
| change_buffer_pages | total_pages | change_buffer_page_percentage |
+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
|                2064 |        8191 |                       25.1984 |
+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+
```

This shows after I inserted a couple of million rows into a test table, about 25% of my buffer pool is occupied by change buffer content waiting to be merged. But it does not tell me which table or index, so it could be changes for other table(s) that are accounting for this.

Over time, the change buffer pages will grow and shrink, as index changes are merged and other INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE traffic comes in.

Comment: The first misunderstanding, as discussed in the comments, was mere terminology. I meant *update* rather than *rebuild* entirely. The second misunderstanding is based on my experience. If I run the second query right after the first one, it would be much slower than executing it a few hours later. Please note that we are talking about an `INSERT` whose data is several times bigger than the change buffer size. After completing the query, InnoDB reads data from the disk into the change buffer to update/merge the secondary index. The problem might not be the way I expressed but there is something.

Comment: Really? The default max change buffer size is 25% of your buffer pool. You INSERT data that is several times larger than this?

Comment: I have change buffer size of 25GB (`innodb_buffer_pool_size=50G`, `innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50`). The size of `ibd` file for that simple table is 147GB for 1.5 billion rows. It's not a web server or something like that. I use MySQL for big data processing.

Comment: But the idea is that the change buffer is a temporary holding space for a subset of index entries from recently inserted rows. Gradually the entries in the change buffer are merged into the tablespace. The change buffer does not have to hold all your indexes at all times. Imagine a huge warehouse, with a small table at the front where today's deliveries are dropped off. Warehouse workers move those items from the small table into their proper place in the warehouse, but the small table lets deliveries get done quickly.

Comment: The question is: does InnoDB create *dirty* pages row by row? Or does it create the pages for the main data and, when the query is completed, start working on the secondary indexes (similar to MyISAM behavior for INSERTing into an empty table)? My experience suggests the latter. Otherwise, we should not have any I/O read activity after a large INSERT query.

Comment: InnoDB modifies pages for indexes and data in the buffer pool. If a given page isn't in the buffer pool, it must be read from disk first. This can affect both index leaf pages and non-leaf pages. So there can be some read I/O activity detectable during inserts.

Comment: not *during* inserts, *after* the completion of the query. If it reads from the disk, it means it has not handled something yet. That something is the secondary indexes.

Comment: I suppose as the change buffer is merged into the index gradually, it needs to read pages from disk. But I have never seen this cause noticeable performance drag on subsequent queries. You may have a very high load on your server, so any slight overhead causes disruption, or else a severely underpowered server for the workload you need to handle.

Answer (score 1):

The I/O activity after a large INSERT probably comes from the delayed "change buffer" activity.

This where updates to non-unique secondary indexes are being updated.

Think of it this way.  When a row is updated/inserted/deleted,

- The top priority (after transaction stuff, etc) is to get the data into the table.
- Updates to secondary indexes need read-update-write to index BTree blocks, but, instead, a small record of what needs to be done is stored in a portion of the buffer pool called the "change buffer".
- As time permits (that is, in the background), these updates are sorted (they are probably kept in a 'priority queue' so they are both accessible and ordered), the read-update-write action taken.
- By batching the updates, fewer reads need to happen.  (That is, read one 16KB index block; insert/delete several 'rows' before writing.)
- The resulting block is now just like any regular block, so it sits as a "dirty" block waiting to be flushed to disk.
- And even later, that index block will actually be written to the disk.

So, yes, a lot of I/O activity.  *But it exists to make the system more efficient and it leads to less I/O*.

I think there are only two settings to control the change buffer:

- Percentage of buffer_pool -- 96% of users leave `innodb_change_buffer_max_size` at the default of "25".
- Which operations to handle -- 94% of users have `innodb_change_buffering = all` (the default)

There is no need to "wait" for it to finish; all of this is handled transparentlyc in the background.

Comment: Your answer is mostly in response to the comments rather than the original question. I have no problem with a lot of I/O activities for creating/updating the secondary index. My question is: How should check if the secondary index has been fully updated so that I can use it in the next query? If run the second query right after the first one, it would be slow, but if I wait for a while, it will be much faster since the required index for the `JOIN` is ready. The question is: how long should I wait?

Comment: @Googlebot - As far as you can tell (without dumping the disk), the indexes are _always_ up to date (within your current transaction).  I added more.

Comment: When the secondary index is still being updated in the background, how can you use it? For small tables, it is not noticeable since the pages are still in the buffer, but for large tables, a majority of the dirty pages have already been flushed to the disk, and InnoDB needs to read them from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Perform `OPTIMIZE TABLE TBL_NAME` on few interval as suggested in MySQL manual.

[Once your data reaches a stable size, or a growing table has increased by tens or some hundreds of megabytes, consider using the OPTIMIZE TABLE statement to reorganize the table and compact any wasted space. The reorganized tables require less disk I/O to perform full table scans. This is a straightforward technique that can improve performance when other techniques such as improving index usage or tuning application code are not practical](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizing-innodb-storage-layout.html)

Additionally, if the combination of `item_id` & `creator_id` are gone be unique then create a composite primary key.

Comment: I disagree with the reference manual...  Unless you recently did a big `DELETE`, using `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is mostly a waste of time on InnoDB tables.

Comment: Yeah it depends on individual experience